# Creating unnumbered parts/chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, header-footer, numbering, starred-version

I'm using the `report` document class for a thesis, and I need to add things like "Acknowledgements" and an "Introduction". I noticed that there is an `\abstract` command which would have been wonderful if applied similarly. How do I add these without messing up the chapters' numbering while being picked up by the ToC in proper order and page numbering?

Comment: For unnumbered chapters, you could just use `\chapter*{Acknowledgements}` and `\chapter*{Introduction}`. These chapter will be formatted similarly to `\chapter`, without the number and not show up in the ToC. Subsequent chapters will be numbered `1`, `2`, ... Is this what you're after? Or are you interested in have something look similar to `\abstract` from the `article` document class? Note that the `report` document class does not provide `\abstract`, only an `abstract` environment.

Comment: I know that this seems like a potentially big shift, but I recommend the `book` class over the `report` class. That way you get the handy `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` switches that handle this for you. Otherwise it's not a lot different from `report`.

Comment: @Werner: I appologize; I meant the abstract environment indeed. Yes it would be nice to have something like that for introductions and acknowledgements.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Well that depends on how different it is. My problem is that I didn't get to experiment much with tex/latex since I've learned about it 3 or 4 months ago and I'm way behind schedule with my thesis, I'd love to learn a new style and how to deal with it, It's just that I might not have the time.

Comment: @JosephWright: Actually now that I've checked my tex file, I actually use \documentclass not \documentstyle.

Comment: Given Mico's answer, it may be best to stick with what you have. It shouldn't take too much effort to move to book, but perhaps the benefits aren't worth the time.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc

Answer (score 210, accepted):

To get unnumbered chapters, parts, sections, subsections, etc, you just affix a `*` (asterisk) to the respective sectioning command; hence, you'd type something like

```
\section*{Acknowledgments}
```

or

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
```

Exactly which sectioning command you ought to use will depend importantly on aspects of the document that you haven't told us about. E.g., should the respective parts begin on a page of their own, and how prominent do you want the caption of the sectioning command to be?

Note that unnumbered parts, chapters, sections, etc are not included automatically in the table of contents (ToC). In case you need some (or all) of them to be included, you should insert an `\addcontentsline` instruction after each such sectioning command. For example, you'd type:

```
\chapter*{Foreword} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
```

The second argument of the `\addcontentsline` instruction -- here, `chapter` -- instructs LaTeX to typeset the entry in a given style, here, "chapter style".

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter{Experiments}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

generates this ToC:

[image]

Comment: in `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}` what does `{toc}` do?

Comment: @snoram - The option `toc` tells LaTeX to write the output to `\jobname.toc`, where `\jobname` is set to the name of your main tex file. Other options are `lot` (to write to `\jobname.lot`, for the "List of Tables", generated by `\listoftables`) and `lof` (to write to `\jobname.lof`, for the "List of Figures", generated by `\listoffigures`. (Note, though, that the sample document features a `\tableofcontents` instruction but no `\listoftables` or `\listoffigures` instructions.)

Comment: Many thanks to whoever provided the 100th upvote, earlier today! It yielded the 6th "Great Answer" gold badge. Thanks so much. This site is really great!!!

Comment: You might also want to add a `\mtcaddchapter` in front of list of tables or figures if you're using one in case minitoc content does not appear. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146461/minitoc-not-appear

Answer (score 49):

Besides adding unnumbered chapters/sections to the ToC, you may also want to ensure that they are correctly displayed in the header/footer. In the `report` and `book` class this may be done by writing, e.g.,

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}
```

for unnumbered chapters (the second argument of `\markboth` controls "right" [odd] pages in `twoside` documents; it may also be left empty) and

```
\section*{Introduction}
\markright{Introduction}
```

for unnumbered sections. (Should you have enabled headers in the `article` class, use `\markboth` in conjunction with `\section*` and `\markright` in conjunction with `\subsection*`.)

Note that the above code snippets will produce non-capitalized names in the header; should you want to capitalize them (as for numbered chapters in the standard classes), replace `Introduction` with `\MakeUppercase{Introduction}`.

Addendum: Both Mico's and my answer refer to the standard document classes (`article`, `book`, `report`). The answers should work for most other classes; however, some classes may offer easier solutions. E.g., with the [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes you may simply use the commands `\addchap`/`\addsec` to create unnumbered chapters/sections that will be displayed in the ToC and the header.

Comment: wow - literally took a couple dozen answer-trials till i found this one. amazing - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A little package on github that might never hit CTAN can be of help here.

It takes care of the entries and the headings automatically.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
    %   indentunnumbered
]{unnumberedtotoc} %get it from https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addchap{unnumbered chapter with toc and head}
\blindtext[10]

\addchap[title for toc and head]{chapter title}
\blindtext[10]
\addsec*{starred addsec}
\blindtext[10]
\addsec{regular addsec}
\blindtext[10]
\addsec*{starred addsec}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{usual chapter}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter*{look at the header}
\blindtext[10]
\addchap*{really nothing, header cleared}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any reason why you haven't contributed this to CTAN?

Comment: @ChrisCharabaruk Because it is not ready yet.