# adding acknowledgement in .tex file

Tags: sectioning, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/creating-unnumbered-chapters-sections-plus-adding-them-to-the-toc-and-or-header)

I want to thank my professor with mention in my LaTeX document, so I need to add a section (without section number) "acknowledgement" before the introduction in my .`tex` file . How can I write there?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To add a non numbered section you just use

```
\section*{Acknowledgement}
```

If you want to insert this section on the table of contents, use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}
```

after the first command.