# Entire chapter as subsection

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, include

[image]I have a document with 3 chapters. I would like the chapter 2 - Dolor, to appear as a section 1.1 in the table of contents, instead of chapter 2.

I have separate file for each of the chapter and it must stay as a seperate file. How can call chapter as a section from inside chapter 1?

MWE is :

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{Lorem}
\include{Dolor}
\include{Sit}
\end{document}
```

The contents of chapter 1 (`Lorem.tex`) are:

```
\chapter{Lorem}
Ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,worman}
\section{Lorem Section 1}
To err is human
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

The contents of chapter 2 (`Dolor.tex`) are:

```
\chapter{Dolor}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a,pines}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

The contents of chapter 3 (`Sit.tex`) are:

```
\chapter{Sit}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor 
\autocite{geer,cicero,companion}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

Comment: Write `\section{Dolor}` instead of `\chapter{Dolor}`.

Comment: But that will only help almost: The `\include` still causes the contents of `Dolor` to appear on a new page. If you don't want that you should probably use `\input`. Note that changing from `\chapter` to `\section` will also change the behaviour of the `refsection`.

Comment: It works good with me, because I want the contents to go to a new page. I've edited the question now, due to a new problem which came up.

Comment: Does that mean you want a 'fake' section heading that appears only in the TOC but not actually in the document body?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: Not pretty, but `\refstepcounter{section}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Dolor}` should do it.

Comment: Hm, this is not working properly. It shows Dolor in TOC but under chapter 3 and in the body of the text, it is showing no contents at all. I want only the heading to be gone, not the content.

Comment: Where did you put the code? It should replace the `\chapter{Dolor}`.

Comment: I replaced \include{Dolor} by the code.

Comment: Aha. That would do to much. Just replace the `\chapter{Dolor}` in the `.tex` file for the second chapter with the suggested bit of code. That code just fakes the heading entry for the TOC. It does nothing more.

Comment: Thanks, now it works :). I replaced \section{Dolor} by your code.

Comment: If you will write your comments as an answer, I can accept it (the green check mark) for the future users.

Comment: Previously, my main tex file was MWE.tex and my chapters were lispum.tex, sit.tex, my section file was dolor.tex.  I had all these tex files in the same folder. Is there a way I could create a subfolder for dolor.tex and the figures inside it and still be able to call \include{dolor.tex}?

Comment: Yes, but you will need a package like https://ctan.org/pkg/import to help LaTeX along if you want to specify the path for graphics relative from `dolor.tex` and not relative from the main file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to have a section heading in the TOC, but not in the actual document you need to use a few more low-level commands.

Replace `\chapter{Dolor}` with `\tocsection{Dolor}` where `\tocsection` is defined as below

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand*{\tocsection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem}
lorem ipsum

\section{Ipsum}
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\tocsection{Dolor}
sit amet
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC of the MWE: 1 Lorem//1.1 Ipsum//1.2 Dolor]

[image: Page one of the MWE: there is no heading for "1.2 Dolor", there is just a new paragraph between "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" and "sit amet"]

Comment: hi @moewe, I have encountered a problem in this answer. I see by using this the page header does not get updated. It sticks to the global name (Lorem). However, I would like the page header to get updated to sub-section name (Dolor). Can you please help?

Comment: @Rouge Can you open a new question with a short example document that reproduces the issue along with a description of what you expect to see instead?

Comment: @Rouge Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433/35864 can help you already, but the exact details will depend on your class and the setup of your headers/footers.