# How to update the header and TOC for star marked the sections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, header-footer

I am using the following MWE. I want to define a chapter, with different sections (Prologue, paper 1, paper 2). I want the star marked sections to show up in TOC, for which I am using a user defined command.

However, I see that the page header, does not get updated. I want the page header to be the same as the star marked section or subsection.
[image]
Can you please help?

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand*{\tocsection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem}
\section{Prologue}
lorem ipsum

The name of this chapter is Lorem. It is chapter 1. This chapter has section called: paper 1, paper 2 and paper 3.

\newpage

\refstepcounter{section}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Paper I}\label{Paper I}

The title of the paper I is defined as.
\begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{10 cm}
            \huge Electrical Properties\\
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}

This paper I, has lot of sections : Introduction, Methods, Results etc.

\subsection*{Introduction}
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\newpage

\refstepcounter{section}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Paper II}\label{Paper II}

The title of the paper II is defined as.
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{10 cm}
        \huge Optical Properties\\
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}

This paper II, also have a lot of sections : Introduction, Methods, Results etc.

\subsection*{Introduction}
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

Comment: hi @moewe, here is the MWE of the problem. Can you help?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to have the header read "Paper I" or "Paper II"?

Comment: For reference, the `\tocsection` came from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/453071/35864. The idea was actually that you'd just write `\tocsection{Paper I}` and `\tocsection{Paper II}` in your document and not the entire complicated definition `\refstepcounter{section}...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need also a \sectionmark command if you want to update the headers:

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand*{\tocsection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem}
\section{Prologue}
lorem ipsum

The name of this chapter is Lorem. It is chapter 1. This chapter has section called: paper 1, paper 2 and paper 3.

\newpage


\refstepcounter{section}%
\sectionmark{Paper 1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Paper I}\label{Paper I}

The title of the paper I is defined as.
\begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{10 cm}
            \huge Electrical Properties\\
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}

This paper I, has lot of sections : Introduction, Methods, Results etc.

\subsection*{Introduction}
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\newpage

\refstepcounter{section}%
\sectionmark{Paper 1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Paper II}\label{Paper II}

The title of the paper II is defined as.
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{10 cm}
        \huge Optical Properties\\
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}

This paper II, also have a lot of sections : Introduction, Methods, Results etc.

\subsection*{Introduction}
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest incorporating `\sectionmark` into `\tocsection` and using that instead of the bare definition of the command. (I know the MWE didn't do that, but it was definitely the intention in the linked answer.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @moewe, it works... Just one last question. can you please how can force lower case word in "Paper I" : I want to write a chemical formula eg Gd2O3. 'd' should be lower case