# chapter without numbering

Tags: chapters, thesis

I am using buthesis format for my thesis. I want introduction and results chapter not to be numbered but when I use \chapter* it didn't show up in the table of content at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433/5764)

Comment: There is also `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\chapter*{Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title}
```

which will add Title and the page number into the ToC as an unnumbered chapter.

Comment: thank you it worked!