# How to completely suppress \chapter number?

Tags: macros, chapters

Similar questions have been asked, but for this can I not find an answer to.

I am using XeLaTeX and the \polyglossia package, and I am using the *book* class, and I don't think it matters, but I am using the \subfiles package also.

I have added:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\chaptername{}}       
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\thechapter{}}
```

However, that results in printing:

". CHAPTER NAME" in the corners of pages. How do I get rid of the ".?"

`\chapter*{}` is out of the question, because then every page prints "Table of Contents."

---

If I have to completely redefine the chapter macro, strangely, I am okay with that, right now...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It is crucial that you tell us which `\documentclass` you are using.

Comment: @campa The book one--I update the question, thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: Probable duplicate.  The answer to this question is given in an answer to [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433).  Look for "`\markboth`".

Comment: You might try \pagestyle{plain}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right thing is to use `\chapter*`. To reset the header you can then use \markboth.

```
\documentclass{book}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Some text}
\markboth{Some text}{Some text}
\newpage
abc
\end{document}
```

The koma classes have an \addchap command

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\addchap{Some text}
\newpage
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that there is a difference between `\chapter*{...}\markboth{...}{...}` and `\addchap{...}`. `\addchap` also adds the current chapter to the ToC.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid writing `\numberline` in the `toc` entry and to redefine `\chaptermark` to only save the chapter title.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for fill-in text

\setmainlanguage{english}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\chaptername{}}       
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\thechapter{}}

\makeatletter
% no number in the toc
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\numberline}{\@gobble}{}{}
% only the title in the header
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]