# Creating section without number

Tags: sectioning

So, currently I want a section such:

```
\section*{...}
```

But it won't appears on my table of contents. And I know if I use `\section{...}` instead, it will appears on the table of contents, but it shows number and I don't want it.

My point is, I want to use section without number in front of it and it includes on my table of contents.

I'll sketch what I mean:

Table Of Contents

Foreword ..........................  i

Endorsement page ..........  ii

Acknowledgement ........... iii

Chapter I ...........................  1

1.1 Section 1 ....................  2

Chapter II ..........................  3

Forgive me to not typing on codes cz I don't know the code. But that's not my point.

So, I'm using `\section*{...}` "on Foreword" until "Acknowledgement" and `\chapter{...}, \section{...}` on Chapter I, II, III

My problem is Foreword until Acknowledgement didn't appear on my table of contents. So, how to set them and put them into my contents?

Thanks! I know this is basic question, cz I'm really newbie. I need your help. I've tried to search about this but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35436/2288) helps.

Comment: @Diaa Thanks, it answers my question.

Comment: (It seems silly for me to ask "Does this answer your question?" when you explicitly said so in the prior comment.  But that's the default text for making this question point to that one.  Welcome to TeX.SE by the way.)