# How to add Acknowledge and certificate in Latex article

Tags: texmaker, article, acknowledgements

I am writing my Dissertation report, and I want to add Acknowledgment and certificate to it . I am using extarticle in my documentclass. I am new to latex and found a similar question here [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433/236895)  but in this question, it is not mentioned how to add certificate and acknowledge for article.

I am using texmaker to write the report.

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give no indication of what the Acknowledgement or certificate should look like. Below are two guesses at what you might want. One is a un-numbered section, as suggested in the question you referenced but ignored. The other is to make up your own style.

```
% ackprob.tex  SE 606496

\documentclass{extarticle}
\title{Dissertation}
\author{A. Student}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section*{Acknowledgements} % unnumbered section not in ToC
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements} % add to ToC
 I acknowledge \ldots  or

\begin
{center}
\large\textbf{Thanks}
%%%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Thanks}  %% add to ToC
%%%
\end{center}
I acknowledge \ldots

\section{First section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: certificate should be written on the top of the page in bold letters, and below it, the content and on the bottom( LHS supervisor name and university name, while on right, signature)

Comment: i just want to know, is there already any format available for it, or we have to manually customize the page to get it?

Comment: Ask another question giving the details of your certificate format. I'm pretty sure that something will be available to give you a start. I imagine that there are many, many certificate formats specified by myriad educational institutes.