# Unnumbered Heading (Section, Chapter) That Appears in TOC (Table of Contents) and PDF Bookmark

Tags: sectioning

How can I add an unnumbered `\chapter` (`\chapter*`) or `\section` (`\section*`) that is also included in the table of contents (TOC) and the PDF bookmarks? Ideally, for the standard classes and Koma classes.

- This question is obviously a duplicate, [see](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/) here for example.
- But I just helped a smart friend with his Ph.D. thesis and he had a hard time solving the question (finding the right answers).
- Therefore, I try to provide here a clearer and more complete question and answer so that future LaTeX users find the solution easier.

### Not Working Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} % or bookmark

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Thanks}
Text.

\section{Introduction}
Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Please leave a comment or edit the answer if I made a mistake or do not follow best practices.*

### Solution for `article` Class

*Thanks, @UlrikeFischer for the hint.*

```
\documentclass{article}

% Small pages for demo purposes.
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% "bookmarksnumbered" is optional: It adds the heading number to the bookmark.
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref} % or "bookmark" package

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Start
% --- ---
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\section{Thanks} % <-- Replace "Thanks" with your heading title.
\sectionmark{Thanks} % <-- Replace "Thanks" with your heading title.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
% --- ---
% End

\blindtext

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{SubSection}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Solution for `book` or `report` Class

*Thanks, @UlrikeFischer for the hint.*

```
\documentclass{book} % or "report"

% Small pages for demo purposes.
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% "bookmarksnumbered" is optional: It adds the heading number to the bookmark.
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref} % or "bookmark" package

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Start
% --- ---
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\chapter{Thanks} % <-- Replace "Thanks" with your heading title.
\chaptermark{Thanks} % <-- Replace "Thanks" with your heading title.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
% --- ---
% End

\blindtext

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Solution for `scrartcl` KOMA Class

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% Small pages for demo purposes.
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% "bookmarksnumbered" is optional: It adds the heading number to the bookmark.
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref} % or "bookmark" package

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

% Start
% --- ---
\addsec{Thanks} % <-- Replace "Thanks" with your heading title.
% --- ---
% End

\blindtext

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{SubSection}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Solution for `scrbook` or `scrreport` KOMA Class

```
\documentclass{scrbook} % or "scrreport"

% Small pages for demo purposes.
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% "bookmarksnumbered" is optional: It adds the heading number to the bookmark.
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref} % or "bookmark" package

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

% Start
% --- ---
\addchap{Thanks} % <-- Replace "Thanks" with your heading title.
% --- ---
% End

\blindtext

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use a numbered section and set the secnumdepth counter to -1

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! I added the Alternative Solution. Your proposal seems to cover more side effects with less effort, right?

Comment: I wouldn't plant \markboth everywhere. If the default behaviour of section doesn't do what you want, redefine \sectionmark.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks again, I updated the two alternatives (nit sure if this is correct though). Going offline now (lunch break). Would you say that I should delete the previous solutions for the article class and the book class?