# Removing the Part Description from Part

Tags: titles, titlesec

I'm trying to got my part headings to just have the part name, without the "Part" prefix. I've been fiddling with the `titlesec` package, but without success.

Any suggestions?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \part{The Best Part}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \\
    \emph{I would like to have this though:}\\
    
    \noindent{\huge \textbf{The Best Part}}
    
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you can see from the reply, a screenshot with "as-is" and a mock-up "as should be" would make things clear. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating unnumbered parts/chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/creating-unnumbered-chapters-sections-plus-adding-them-to-the-toc-and-or-header)