# redefining running head locally

Tags: sectioning, books

In the LaTeX classical book class, running heads display current chapter and current section. I am totally OK with this.

Sometimes, however, I need to add an un-numbered section, usually at the end of the chapter (historical notes, exercises, etc.). Unfortunately, the running head continues to display the name of  previous numbered section. Can this be remedied? Precisely, can I force the LaTeX to display the un-numbered section's name?

Comment: Immediately after the `\section*`, add `\markright{<name>}`.  That should change the running head on the right-hand page.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: This should be covered by [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433)  Duplicate candidate