# Whyt does the list of figures title keeps showing in my other pages

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: List of figures keep showing in other pages]

As you can see, the title "indice de figuras" (list of figures) keeps showing in all my other pages, I have separated all my chapters in different carpets, so the code i used to add the toc and the list of figures is just this:

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice de figuras}

Also, i wanted my toc and list of figures to appear on the toc, It did, but the page numeration was wrong, if you can help me with that also I would be very thankful.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Although it's impossible to say for certain, since you haven't identified your document class, this could happen if your next chapter starts with `\chapter*`.  Please provide a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.  Then we won't have to guess.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it does starts with `\chapter*`, here is the [link](https://es.overleaf.com/read/pkgqqsmfchvx)

Comment: You should add `\markboth{<text>}{<text>}` immediately after the `\chapter*` line, as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91468